# C# .NET - Is there a way to determine my app's memory usage per class/object type in runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-leaks

I have a C# .NET app running in the cloud (Heroku) and from time to time I'm experiencing memory leaks.

I would like to get a detailed memory usage statistics from my app, in runtime, because I cannot attach a debugger to the remote process.

It would be great if I could get something like the follwing from inside of my C# code during runtime:

```
> dumpheap -stat

Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
...
00007f6c1eeefba8      576        59904 System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
00007f6c1dc021c8     1749        95696 System.SByte[]
00000000008c9db0     3847       116080      Free
00007f6c1e784a18      175       128640 System.Char[]
00007f6c1dbf5510      217       133504 System.Object[]
00007f6c1dc014c0      467       416464 System.Byte[]
00007f6c21625038        6      4063376 testwebapi.Controllers.Customer[]
00007f6c20a67498   200000      4800000 testwebapi.Controllers.Customer
00007f6c1dc00f90   206770     19494060 System.String
Total 428516 objects
```

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak)

I was unable to find anything so far, neither of: a free library, a third party tool nor a code snippet.

Comment: There are memory profilers like [Jetbrains's dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) or VS build in [profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage-without-debugging2?view=vs-2022). You can try using those. Or you can try writing something using [ClrMD](https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd). There is also [dotnet-dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-dump) global tool.

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks! I am looking for a tool that can preferably run in-the-process (as a part of my C# application), as I am unable to attach to my app running in Heroku cloud. `dotnet-dump` could be a good alternative, I'm not sure about the memory/cpu implications of a complete dump though.

Comment: @adamsfamily It will slowdown your application during dumping a memory for a while. The time period depends on the application memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/). This tool will show you memory leak suggestion, total memory, memory of each type object...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for something that can run in the process (as a part of my C# ASP.NET project), as I am unable to attach to the process running in Heroku cloud. Can DotMemory be deployed as a part of the project?

Comment: @adamsfamily Yes, dotMemory has a console version for gathering a profile which can be deployed anywhere.

Comment: @adamsfamily I've missed the "in runtime" part of your question. So, there are some additions. dotMemory will not allow determining it in runtime, it will get a memory snapshot which should be analyzed in the GUI application by human. Look at dotMemory Unit framework, despite it was designed mostly for testing it will provide you with numbers you need. But note, that running your application under profiler slows it down significantly. Also getting a memory snapshot stops the app completely during traversing a memory. So, this solution is not for production server.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I would be happier with something that I can analyze with my own code during runtime because that would allow me to draw statistics, prepare alerts, etc. It's starting to be clear to me that it's not (easily) doable.